# Tell me about non-MD5/SHA1 key fingerprints

Tags: public-key

I understand there are specifications for public-key fingerprints that use modern hash algorithms like SHA2. What are they?

Answer (score 2):

Any secure hash algorithm can be used to generate a public key fingerprint - your choice depends entirely on which hash is expected by the other party.

Comment: I recall reading some standard about taking the SHA2 hash of a DER representation of the private key, and a standard name for this kind of fingerprint.

Comment: Yes I did see this when looking around for an answer for you - I'm not overly familiar with fingerprinting but is this the document you're looking for? http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-smime-sha2-11#ref-SHS